# Do i need to be connected to the internet everytime i want to create gluon mobile project

Tags: javafxports, gluon-mobile

When my computer is offline, i cannot create mobile project using gluon mobile. Here is the stacktrace (the top line):

```
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle installation 'C:\tools\gradle'.
```

Once I'am connected to the Internet, i can create projects without any issue.
so the Internet connection is required to create gluon poject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have created your first project, all the main dependencies are downloaded and installed in your local repositories, so you can make use of them to create a new project without being connected to the Internet.

For that you need to use this option when calling any gradle task: `--offline`.

From your IDE you can set it as a default option:

- NetBeans -> Preferences->Miscellaneous->Gradle, Gradle arguments, add `--offline`.
- IntelliJ -> Preferences->Build, Execution, Deployment->Gradle, select offline work under Gradle Global Settings.
- Eclipse -> Select a task, right click, Open Gradle Run Configuration... -> Arguments, add `--offline` to Program Arguments.

Note that some versions (jfxmobile plugin, charm, ...) are updated remotely in the gradle.build file, so when offline you'll need to make sure you have a proper version.